# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar los diferentes valores de una consulta?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando hacer una función para desempates en una liga de futbol.

Suponiendo que lo máximo son 39 puntos y recorro todos los puntos que puede tener el equipo del 0 al 39 (el 39 es el máximo ya que son 13 partidos. `13 x 3 = 39`. Aunque los gane todos imposible que pase de ese puntaje), haciendo lo que veis en el código como puedo almacenar los dos equipos que tienen mismos puntos.

Es decir, en la consulta tengo 2 o mas equipos que tienen los mismos puntos.
Quiero almacenarlos en `$equipo1` y `$equipo2` para luego posteriormente hacer un desempate si han jugado entre ellos.

Nota: los partidos no se pueden empatar. Solo ganan o pierden. En caso de empate es gol de oro.

¿Cómo puedo guardarlos?

Este es el código que tengo por el momento:

```
$division = 'Primera Division';

for ($contadorpuntos = 0; $contadorpuntos <= 39; $contadorpuntos++){

    $sql1 = "SELECT equipo FROM equipos WHERE division ='$division' AND puntos = '$contadorpuntos'";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result1) >= 2) {

        while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {   
            $equipo1 = $fila['equipo'];  //¿ES CORRECTO?
            $equipo2 = $fila['equipo'];  //¿ES CORRECTO?            
        }   
    }   
}

mysql_close("$host", "$username", "$password");
exit;

?>
```

La estructura de la tabla equipos es la siguiente:

```
equipo  varchar(20)
nombre  varchar(20)
apellidos   varchar(40)
email   varchar(40)
telefono    varchar(9)
movil   varchar(9)
division    varchar(15)
puesto  int(2)
desempate int(2)
puntos int(2)
partidosganados int(2)
partidosperdidos int(2)
golesafavor int(2)
golesencontra int(2)
```

Comment: Deberías hacer sólo una query para obtener los dos equipos con mayor puntaje y luego hacer una comparación. Para poder hacerte una respuesta me vendría bien que me pases la estructura de la tabla `equipos`.

Comment: Lo que quiero no es escontrar los dos equipos con mayor puntaje sino que a través de los puntos saber si hay 2 o mas equipos que tengan los mismos puntos para después desempatarlos por golaverage o diferencia.

Comment: Claro pero lo que venías haciendo es muy poco performante ya que estás haciendo 39 request a la DB cuando podrías hacer sólo uno y después chequearlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si lo que quieres es guardar en una variable un listado por division y los equipos que aparecen en esa division con los mismos puntos, puedes hacerlo en el codigo tuyo, modificando el bucle while, y guardando de la siguiente manera:

```
    $equipo[$division][] = $fila['equipo'];
```

En tu codigo seria algo como:

```
$division = 'Primera Division';

for ($contadorpuntos = 0; $contadorpuntos <= 39; $contadorpuntos++){

    $sql1 = "SELECT equipo FROM equipos WHERE division ='$division' AND puntos = '$contadorpuntos'";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result1) >= 2) {

        while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {  
            $equipo[$division][$contadorpuntos][] = $fila['equipo'];           
        }   
    }   
}

mysql_close("$host", "$username", "$password");
exit;
```

con esto tendrias un array tal que:

```
$equipo => [
  "primera division" => 
   [
      "0" => ["equipo1", "equipo2", "equipo4"],
      "1" => ["equipo6", "equipo7"],
      "2" => [],
      ...
   ]
]
```

Sin embargo, esto no es muy optimo. Estas haciendo 40 consultas (de 0 a 39), para sacar los equipos de esa puntuacion. Seria mas optimo hacer la consulta con un agrupado por puntuacion. Algo tipo:

> SELECT equipo, puntos FROM equipos WHERE division = $division ORDER BY puntos;

con esto, tu consulta sacaria algo como:

```
"equipo1"  0
"equipo2"  0
"equipo4"  0
"equipo6"  1
"equipo7"  1 
...
```

Y ahora tu codigo podria ser:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT equipo, puntos FROM equipos WHERE division = $division ORDER BY puntos";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);

while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {  
    $equipo[$division][$fila['puntos'][] = $fila['equipo'];           
}
```

Ahora, si lo que quieres es obtener directamente que equipos tienen la misma puntuacion y se tienen que enfrentar entre ellos(1 a 1)creo que tu solucion pasa por utilizar una consulta como la siguiente:

> SELECT puntos.equipo1, equipo.equipo1, equipo.equipo2 FROM equipos as equipo1, equipos
>   as equipo2  WHERE equipo.equipo1 <> equipo.equipo2 AND
>   division.equipo1 =$division  AND division.equipo2 = $division AND
>   puntos.equipo1 = puntos.equipo2 ORDER BY puntos.equipo1

con esto, tendrias un listado de aquellos equipos que tienen la misma puntuacion. Luego recorrerias ese listado, y "enfrentas" a cada uno de los equipos.

Te recuerdo: la consulta es una aproximacion... revisala para ajustarla a tus necesidades.

El resultado de la consulta seria algo como:

```
puntos    equipo1          equipo2
1         santander          oviedo
1         santander          aviles
1         oviedo             aviles
2         murcia             sevilla
3         albacete           lugo
4   ...
...
31        barcelona          madrid
```

Comment: Donde pongo esa consulta? Quieres decir que esta bien el código que tengo de momento? equipo1 y equipo2 son diferentes en el ejemplo que pongo? En tu consulta, si se dieran 3 o mas?

Comment: en este caso solo saldrian enfrentados entre si aquellos que tienen la misma puntuacion, y serian dos a dos. si hay 3, equipos con la misma puntuacion, te van a salir 3 lineas (enfrentando uno contra otro). Solo tendrias que hacer la consulta que te indico, recorrerla y obtener esos equipos, que son los que se van a enfrentar.

Comment: perdoname pero no lo entiendo muy bien. lo que necesito es saber los equipos que tienen los mismos puntos (sean 2,3 o 50) Esa consulta que pones seria la que deberia ir en $sql1?

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta. te pongo una posible salida de la consulta, para que veas que te aparecen enfrentados los equipos que tienen los mismos puntos.

Comment: Me quedo con tu primer ejemplo que es lo que mas acorde va con lo que estaba haciendo. Una vez realizado ya podre depurar y mejorar el código. Es decir que en el array creado si quiero acceder al 'equipo4' seria '$equipo[$division][$contadorpuntos][3]' Correcto?

Comment: para acceder al equipo4 tendrias que utilizar el indice 2 (recuerda que empiezan en 0). seria $equipo[$division][$contadorpuntos][2]